# Coluna virtual extraida de um json no MySql não recebe o valor NULL

Tags: mysql, json

Tenho um coluna virtual chamada '_cpf' que é extraída da coluna '_document' em json. Segue abaixo a seguinte query:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `_document` json DEFAULT NULL,
 `_id` varbinary(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`_document`,'$.id'))) STORED NOT NULL,
 `_cpf` varchar(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`_document`,'$.cpf'))) VIRTUAL,
 `_externalId` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`_document`,'$.externalId'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
 `_created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `_updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY (`_empresaId`, `_cpf`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

O problema é quando eu insiro um linha com o cpf igual á null, a coluna virtual salva como varchar e não NULL, como deveria. Ou seja, se eu fizer um 'select * from user where _cpf is null' ele não funciona.

Existe também o problema na inserção de outra linha com _cpf null e com o mesmo valor na coluna _empresaId, resultando o erro de valores duplicados do comando UNIQUE KEY.

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi incluir na query do create table o seguinte comando

```
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN _document->>'$.cpf' = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE _document->>'$.cpf' END) STORED,
```